# How to make an addition of a git repo?

Tags: git

For example, I have a git repo (named repo) and code base (named mycode). It is managed by git. And I have 100 git commits already.

Today I make 5 more git commits in office. And I want to get only these 5 commits back to home. Then I can pacth them to the code base at home.
**How to get these 5 commits' patch(not only the 5th patch)?**

If I simply use 'diff' and 'patch' commands then I only get the last/5th patch. But what I want is to keep all commits history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in [`git bundle`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html).

**For example:**

At the office:

```
git bundle create my.bundle HEAD@{5}..
```

At home:

```
git pull my.bundle
```

Of course, you'd probably want to use a dedicated `tag`/`branch` instead working out what to use in place of `HEAD@{5}` (i.e. 5 commits) each time.